# CSS Border Styling CSS, HTML & PHP

Tags: html, css

I would like to add a border style of white to the bottom of td-fault table only.

My CSS CODE:

```
background, body{
background-color: black;
}

table-eng, p{
width: 650%;
font-size: 15pt;
color: #ffffff;
border-bottom-style: none;  
}

table-cust, tr{
font-size: 13pt;
color: #4CBB17;
}

td-fault, td{
font-size: 11pt;
color: #ffffff;
border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}
```

Here is my HTML/PHP:

```
<html>
<link href="../css/job-board.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="backgroud">
<body>
<table>
<td>
<?php 
include('connectionDB.php');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM [Support_DB].[dbo].['Job info$'] WHERE [Job Completed?]= 0 AND [Attended by]='James'";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $results=$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        ?>
<div id='table-eng'>
<table>
<tr>
<th>
<p>James</p>
</th>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<?php foreach ($results as $row) { 
echo "<div id='table-cust'>";
echo"<table>";
echo"<tr>";
echo"<th align='left'>";
echo $row['Customer'];
echo"</th>";
echo"<th>";
echo $row['Job Number'];
echo"</th>";
echo"</tr>";
echo"<tr>";
echo"</div>";
//echo"<div id='td-fault'>";
echo"<td class='td-fault'>";
echo wordwrap($row['Fault'],85,"<br>\n",TRUE);
echo"</td>";
echo"</tr>";
//echo"</div>";
 echo"</table>";
 //echo"</div>";
//echo"</div>";
        }?>
```

The company Name and job number need to be in white if possible on a continuous line so looks smoother as I nearly had it how I wanted it but I mucked up and couldn't get it correct again.

Comment: The PHP isn't relevant to your question. Please post the rendered HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is because you're missing the `.` for `td-fault` in your CSS.

Try the following:

```
.td-fault {
  font-size: 11pt;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}
```

Also `table-eng` and `table-cust` is missing `#` like so
`#table-eng` and `#table-cust`

Comment: Could you also help with why some of my job lists for other staff appear correctly ie. In a straight line where others appear in the middle of the table for example my jobs JAMES appears in the middle of the table where MARTINS is the same code appears correctly?

Comment: Try to remove the `echo"</div>";` above the `//echo"<div id='td-fault'>";`. If that doesn't help, feel free to post another question with the rendered version of the page so we can have a look.

Comment: I have removed all the commeted code out and the div tag to no joy it wont let me post another question at the moment but i am bit un-easy on posting the rendered version as it has clients data on.

Comment: try to replace your foreach contents with https://pastebin.com/B2FQsiqN - you definitively need to indent your code to have a better view of any missing tag